# Using Material Design (materializecss) Multiple Select CSS with Mono-Select Behavior

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, materialize

Materializecss has a cool CSS for multiple select. But when I select the normal select list, I have to let that CSS go.

http://jsfiddle.net/mulgey/48wk502o/11/

On this example I have tried to turn the multi selecting off by adding:

```
var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {
  isMultiple: false
});
```

But it did not work.

So may you help me on deactivating multi-select behavior for this CSS?

Regards to the community

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".input-field span" ).click(function() {
        let selecty = $(this).parent().siblings(".selected");
        selecty.trigger( "click" );
      });
```

If you add this code, your multiple-select CSS will stay but work as mono-select.